# How redirect to login page when got 401 error from ajax call in React-Router?

Tags: ajax, reactjs, react-router, superagent

I am using React, React-Router and Superagent. I need authorization feature in my web application. Now, if the token is expired, I need the page redirect to login page.

I have put the ajax call functionality in a separated module and the token will be send on each request's header. In one of my component, I need fetch some data via ajax call, like below.

```
 componentDidMount: function() {

    api.getOne(this.props.params.id, function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
        this.setErrorMessage('System Error!');
      } else if (this.isMounted()) {
        this.setState({
          user: data
        });
      }
    }.bind(this));

  },
```

If I got 401 (Unauthorized) error, maybe caused by token expired or no enough privilege, the page should be redirected to login page. Right now, in my api module, I have to use `window.loication="#/login"` I don't think this is a good idea.

```
var endCallback = function(cb, err, res) {

  if (err && err.status == 401) {
    return window.location('#/login');
  }

  if (res) {
    cb(err, res.body);
  } else {
    cb(err);
  }
};

get: function(cb) {
  request
    .get(BASE_URL + resources)        
    .end(endCallback.bind(null, cb));
},
```

But, I can't easily, call the react-router method in my api module. Is there an elegant way to implemented this easy feature? I don't want to add an error callback in every react components which need authorized.

Answer (score 3):

I would try something like this:

1. Use the component's context to manipulate the router (`this.context.router.transitionTo()`).
2. Pass this method to the API callout as a param.

```js
// component.js
,contextTypes: {
  router: React.PropTypes.func
},
componentDidMount: function() {
    api.getOne(this.props.params.id, this.context.router, function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
        this.setErrorMessage('System Error!');
      } else if (this.isMounted()) {
        this.setState({
          user: data
        });
      }
    }.bind(this));
},


// api.js
var endCallback = function(cb, router, err, res) {

  if (err && err.status == 401) {
    return router.transitionTo('login');
  }

  if (res) {
    cb(err, res.body);
  } else {
    cb(err);
  }
};

get: function(cb, router) {
  request
    .get(BASE_URL + resources)        
    .end(endCallback.bind(null, cb, router));
},
```

I know you didn't want a callback on each authenticated component, but I don't think there's any special react-router shortcuts to transition outside of the router.

The only other thing I could think of would be to spin up a brand new router on the error and manually send it to the login route. But I don't think that would necessarily work since it's outside of the initial render method.

Comment: @bard For your understanding, do you think there any drawback if I use `window.location('#/login');`

Comment: @chris if you change your login route then you'll have to update all references to it. If you use the name of the route you can change the path as much as you like without having to change other areas of your app.

Comment: You couldwrite a wrapper that hides the call to window thus never needing to update these references.